# PHP - Set an array inside an array then get the value of it back in json (IPN FILE)

Tags: php, arrays, json, paypal-ipn

So this code is for my IPN for Selly.

In Selly's response on their webhook, it shows:

```
{27 items
"id":"9657d3ae-aad3-449f-9b5a-1accd9919698"
"product_id":"upgrade"
"email":"benzahdd55@outlook.com"
"ip_address":"127.0.0.1"
"country_code":"US"
"product_title":"Selly Pro 1 Month"
"user_agent":"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWeb..."
"value":"1.0"
"quantity":1
"currency":"USD"
"gateway":"PayPal"
"risk_level":0
"status":100
"delivered":NULL
"crypto_value":NULL
"crypto_address":NULL
"crypto_channel":NULL
"crypto_received":0
"crypto_confirmations":0
"referral":NULL
"usd_value":"1.0"
"exchange_rate":"1.0"
"coupon_id":NULL
"custom":{}0 items
"created_at":"2019-12-05T13:25:39.000+00:00"
"updated_at":"2019-12-05T13:25:39.000+00:00"
"webhook_type":1
}
```

As you can see, it shows the `"custom":{}0 items`

In the shop page, I am setting the data like this:

```
                                        $custom_array = array(
                                            'custom_id' => $product_id
                                        );

                                        $data = array(
                                            "title" => $productName,
                                            "gateway" => "PayPal",
                                            "email" => $clientEmail,
                                            "value" => $after_coupon_value,
                                            "currency" => "USD",
                                            "custom" => $custom_array,
                                          'return_url' => 'https://acchub.org/shop?product='.$productName,
                                          'webhook_url' => 'https://acchub.org/sellywh?secret='.$secret
                                        );                                          
                                        $data_curl = json_encode($data);
```

In my IPN page, I am doing this to get the custom field:

```
                    $data = json_decode($webhookContent);
                    $productName = $data->product_title;
                    $orderId = $data->id;
                    $amount = $data->value;
                    $email = $data->email;
                    $status = $data->status;
                    $gateway = $data->gateway;
                    parse_str($data->custom, $_CUSTOM);
                    $custom_id = $CUSTOM['custom_id'];

                    mail('admin@site.com', 'worked fine', $custom_id);
```

The above code works for the other params, such as gateway, status, email etc.
But the $custom_id field in my email I get is empty.
Ask any questions for more of the code, but this is the main concept

Comment: missing underscore `_` ... `$_CUSTOM` in `parse_str($data->custom, $_CUSTOM);` vs. `$CUSTOM` in `$custom_id = $CUSTOM['custom_id'];`

Answer (score 0):

So it turns out Selly do not currently support the `custom` input in their API.

They told me to assign it as I assigned the secret in the shop (front) page.

So it would be `example.com/ipn?secret=blabla&custom=51`